# Rmarkdown with Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

i'm trying to convert a part of my Rshiny in Rmarkdown, but when i try to run this example i get an error, how can i handle it?
this code is part of an example of Rshiny app, but when i try to run something is wrong
or could you help me to find some script to print some tables and graphs from Rshiny into Rmarkdown?

```
Aserver <-function(input, output) {
  
  regFormula <- reactive({
    as.formula(paste('mpg ~', input$x))
  })
  
  output$regPlot <- renderPlot({
    par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1))
    plot(regFormula(), data = mtcars, pch = 19)
  })
  
  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
        input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
      ))
    },
    
    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')
      
      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
      
      library(rmarkdown)
      out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
        input$format,
        PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
      ))
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )
  
}
Aui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Download a PDF report',
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText(),
      selectInput('x', 'Build a regression model of mpg against:',
                  choices = names(mtcars)[-1]),
      radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                   inline = TRUE),
      downloadButton('downloadReport')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('regPlot')
    )
  )
)



shinyApp(Aui, Aserver)
```

this is the error

```
Warning: Error in abs_path: The file 'report.Rmd' does not exist.
  [No stack trace available]
```

Thanks

Comment: You should have `report.Rmd` available in `getwd()` directory, is this the case?

Comment: no, when i click on download i can select the path, but nothing happens, should i need to create something additional for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should distinghish two paths:

- the path where the application is installed/running
- the path where you are going to download the result of knitting the Markdown doc

You can get the path where the application is running with `getwd()`.
If you don't explicitly specify a path, the `report.Rmd` should be located on the same directory as the application so that the application can use it.

Make sure `Report.Rmd` is in `getwd()` directory, or specify the path of `Report.Rmd` :

```
render(file.path('/custom/directory','report.Rmd'), ...
```